# Exporting in Premiere single frame as long video

Tags: windows-10, adobe-photoshop, adobe-premiere

I'm simply adding an image (1MB) to audio (3MB) and I get a 250MB output video.

Surely there's a way to render this way smaller, using some form of variable bit/frame rate

I'm using the Default H.264 -> Youtube 1080P template.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get an answer on how to do in Premiere, you can do it using the freely-available open source tool ffmpeg.

`ffmpeg -i file-you-just-exported.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v h264 -b:v 500k name-of-file-to-save-as.mp4`

For a 3 minute video with good quality audio this would take up around 15MB.

`-c:a copy` don't re-encode the audio, just embed it from the source as is

`-c:v h264` use h264 as the codec

`-b:v 500k` bitrate to use for the video - you can try playing with this if the quality's not what you want

Comment: DO you reckon I can put this in a .bat script for ease of use? I'm regularly pairing my album art with my music.

Comment: structure is: `foldern:***songname**-> thumbnail.png, audio.mp3`

Comment: I.e, theres a folder called, x containing thumbnail.png and audio.mp3, and i want to output "youtube.mp4"

Comment: Nevermind, i thought this was a renderer, but it simply compresses..

Comment: Fixed by scaling. Thanks for this answer, so much more convenient and efficient than using premiere